# new blog post does not appear in blog after publishing

Tags: posts, blog

I can not see the new post I created for the blog.

In Settings > Permalinks > I changed it from Post name to Default
and
switched from a Theme Trust design to the default theme (twenty twelve).
I did not deactivate the plugins.

I can still see http://margaretsphotoplace.com/?p=741
but not http://margaretsphotoplace.com/?p=2686

Comment: Empty your website Trash or see if you have even published it or not?

Answer (score 0):

Retry to flush the rewrite rules or else just remove the htaccess file if you're using default.